# UiPath orchestrator robot is not displaying in job

Tags: uipath, uipath-studio, uipath-robot

I have created the below in UiPath:

1. Create Machine and copied the machine ID in UiPath Robot
2. Create Robot and Environment
3. Link the Environment to Robot
4. Publish Package
5. Create Process [image]and select ENV
6. In JOB, after selecting the Process then ROBOT is not showing.

Answer (score 1):

Under Point 2 you said that you have created an **environment**. But I cannot see that from your image. So doublecheck that you have created such an environment. For a usual system this will be **Dev** and **Prod**. So create them under:

`Management` -> `Robots` -> `Environments`

[image: Environment window]

Now you can see them under **Jobs**.

Answer (score 1):

Your Robot is of type Studio, but needs to be either Unattended or Non-Production to be able to start jobs from Orchestrator.
This is a recent change discussed with the community on the forum:
https://forum.uipath.com/t/studio-scheduling-will-be-disabled-thoughts-pending-jobs/200090